# Hudson build defaults

Tags: build, continuous-integration, hudson

This has been a fairly long-standing problem for us with our Hudson installation, and searching around the Hudson Wiki / Issue Tracker hasn't yielded any insight to this.

The question: Is it possible to set certain default values for a maven2 build in Hudson? For example, we want all our projects to run the "clean" goal before a build, we want all our builds to poll the SCM hourly, and we want all our builds to deploy to our maven repository on build success.

Right now, we have to manually set these setting for every project individually, which can be rather time consuming as we have 30+ different projects all being managed by Hudson. This is especially annoying if we need to change a particular setting that will affect all projects (e.g. change the repository URL).

Given that I couldn't find any mention of this on the Wiki or Issue Tracker leads me to believe that I'm missing something obvious, but I cannot find an answer on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have a look at the [Configuration Slicing Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org//display/HUDSON/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin)? This might solve at least some of your questions. Otherwise I would recommend a good text editor that can run mass replacements (using regular expressions) for (all) files in a folder.

Comment: Actually after reading your question again, since you only want to have default values, wouldn't it be sufficient if you just copy an existing job or a 'template' job?